# filter ids by comma separated nvchar ids

Tags: sql

imagine i have a simple table which contains `Id` (primary key) and `Name` rows. 
Now i have a comma separated ids list like- `2,5,6`. I just want to take these comma separated ids then get compare each of id with existing data. And return only those ids which is unique that's means not exists in database. Please note the output also should be same as like input format that's means comma separated format. I am using Microsoft SQL server 2017

What i already tried is like bellow:

```
select * from DemoTable where Id 2,5,6 not in DemoTable
```

But this seems not correct syntax. How can i fix it?

Comment: `select * from DemoTable where Id not in (2,5,6)`

Comment: "Please note the output also should be same as like input format that's means comma separated format.", should be "1,2,3" right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this. You need to look from other side in this problem. I found it very interesting.

Actually you have a list of id's as base, and you want to exclude id from the string which are not in some table. So first we need to find the list of id's, after that we'll exclude them from the id's of table to get our desired result. At the end you may use `stuff` or `string_agg` to convert your final result into `,` separated string.

```
select Value from (
select value from string_split('1,2,3',',')) as t 
where t.value not in (select id from demotable)
```

You may check this link for working fiddle.[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3b6a4/6).

Comment: You are close but i want to get output only those ids which is unique from my provided list 2,5,6. Suppose if 5 exists then it will return only 2,6 something like that

Comment: You are the king of SQL! Thanks a lot my dear brother. Works

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select string_agg(val, ',') as result
from (
    select value as val from string_split('1,2,3',',')) as t 
where t.val not in (select id from tableA)
```

**Result: (comma separated)**

```
1,2,3
```